# Load Mobile Version when visited with Mobile otherwise load Desktop Version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

can someone exlpain me how i can call my Mobile Version of a Website only when i visit by Phone and my Desktop Version of the Website when i visit everything that's bigger then 500px?

I have created a Mobile Website and a Desktop Website seperatly.
Is it possible to check the width with jQuery and then call either the Mobile or Desktop Version?

i tried it like this

on my Desktop Version:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 500px)" href="../FolderPath/index.html" >
```

on my Mobile Version:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="../FolderPath/index.html">
```

but i think i'm totally wrong.

hope someone can help me, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am down voted your question because your post does not show enough research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect screen size with JavaScript and redirect user to mobile site if screen size is less than 500px

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 500) {
        document.location = "mobile/index.html";
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks man it works :) i tried it also with Javascript but couldn't get it to work, now that i see it, it's soo simple, thanks again for your fast help :)